# Is it possible to restrict certain ASMX web service methods to GET or POST only?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asmx

Unfortunately, I'm doing some work on a (legacy) project that is build with ASP.NET Web Forms. I can't migrate it to ASP.NET MVC (so please don't suggest that as an answer).

I wish to create an API to expose some of our data. So, I went a head and made a web service. Pretty simple stuff. BUT, for the first few methods, I wish to expose them only as HTTP-GET. For my last method, I wish to expose this only as HTTP-POST.

I'm so used to using ASP.NET MVC, which is why I really love this RESTful way of programming, but I'm not sure how to do this with my web service?

I'm using a URL Rewriter, so that handles the 'RESTfull' consuming of the api (it's lame, but it works).

So, is there a way to block a web service to only accept the HTTP verb?

Comment: This doesn't sound like REST to me. URL rewriting doesn't have anything to do with REST, nor do HTTP verbs. Please remove the [rest] tag if it's not accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following above the method declaration:

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
```

This forces the method to respond only to POST. Set to true if you want the method to respond to GET. The gotcha here is that you need to be using ASP.NET 3.5 or the ASP.NET AJAX Extensions for ASP.NET 2.0. You can read more about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.usehttpget.aspx)

Comment: If i set it to TRUE, does that mean POST is unavailable?

Comment: That restricts the entire service to POST, not just a single method like I think he's asking.

Comment: The ScriptMethod attribute can be set and changed per method, not just for the whole class.

Answer (score 1):

You can [enable GET in the web.config](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819267), using:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

To restrict a single method to POST, you can test HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod at runtime.

Comment: yep - that i know of. BUT, how can i restrict a single method .. if both GET and POST are enabled? That config setting is for _all_ web methods....

Comment: You can test the HttpMethod property at runtime.  Updated answer.

Answer (score -3):

I'm pretty sure the .net web service class accepts only posted variables.

Comment: Nope, it accepts GET, POST and SOAP (edit: even though SOAP isn't an HTTP-Verb).