# How to force ASP.NET Web Service expose only HTTP-POST interface

Tags: asp.net, web-services, http, wsdl

After creating a new ASP.NET Web Service I want it only to [support HTTP-POST for incoming data](http://eduzine.edujini-labs.com/archives/9-Web-Services-in-ASP.Net-HTTP-POST-vs.-HTTP-SOAP.html). How can I force the WSDL to reflect that policy?

How should the WSDL for the clients look like to enable only HTTP-POST and **disallow SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 in the WSDL**?

The solution:

```
<system.web>
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <clear />
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
    <add name="Documentation"/>
  </protocols>
  <conformanceWarnings>
    <remove name='BasicProfile1_1'/>
  </conformanceWarnings>
</webServices>
```

Comment: I modified my answer - the new answer should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: [Is it possible to restrict certain ASMX web service methods to GET or POST only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276098/is-it-possible-to-restrict-certain-asmx-web-service-methods-to-get-or-post-only)

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
```

**Edit - more info**

Have you tried this in your web.config?

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <webServices>
         <protocols>
            <clear />
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
         </protocols>
      </webServices>
   <system.web>
</configuration>
```

This idea came to me after reading this documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccbk8w5h(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Yet can the protocols be configured within code via c# attributes?

Comment: I wasn't able to find any documented way of doing that.  The web.config solution was the only one I could find for what you were asking.